# How to anotate the attribute in the Entity if the table attribute has a default value of clock_timestamp()?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

On the Postgres database, I have a table with "insert_time" attribute (timestamptz), which has a default value of clock_timestamp() function.

In Java, I have created the Entity from the table but when I like to insert a new record into the table the insert_time has a value of null instead of clock_timestamp().

How to properly annotate the Entity so if the insert_time is not passed in Java that a "default value" of clock_timestamp() is used on a table itself?

or how to read clock_timestamp() in the entity if the attribute is set to null.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply annotated the JPA entity and get the value returned by the function `clock_timestamp()`

In order to get that value to your code you will need to do a query

```
SELECT clock_timestamp();
```

But you can use JPA-Listeners to achieve something similar:

```
public class TimestampEntityListener {
    @PrePersist
    public void setDefaultTime(BaseEntity entity) {
       if(entity.getInsertTime() == null) {
           entity.setInsertTime(new Timestamp((new Date()).getTime())):
       }
    }
}

@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners({TimestampEntityListener.class})
public abstract class BaseEntity {...}
```

Now, if you're really interested in having the DB control the time of the insertion, and not delegate your application to do it, you can modify the above code and wire an entityManager in it so that you can perform that select against the DB and just set that value directly.

**Update:** on how to delegate the entityListener to query the Database

```
public class TimestampEntityListener {
        @Autowired
        EntityManager entityManager;

        @PrePersist
        public void setDefaultTime(BaseEntity entity) {
           AutowireHelper.autowire(this, this.entityManager);
           if(entity.getInsertTime() == null) {
               Timestamp timestamp = (Timestamp)entityManager.createNativeQuery("select clock_timestamp()").getSingleResult();
               entity.setInsertTime(timestamp):
           }
        }
    }
```

You can use this class for [AutowireHelper](https://github.com/intel/intelRSD/blob/master/PODM/SW/node-composer/src/main/java/com/intel/rsd/nodecomposer/utils/beans/AutowireHelper.java) and with the above code it should work out of the box as long as your entities will extend the **BaseEntity**.

Comment: Hi Vladucu, can you please write down how to annotate the Entity attribute to pass the clock_timestamp()?   (small example) thank you

Comment: @Vape you cannot do that... The only way is to do it how I wrote in the comment with an EntityListener. You can update that Listener to make that query to your database `SELECT clock_timestamp();`  and set the returned value here `entity.setInsertTime(`

Comment: Ok.. need to investigate  how to do that. For now, I can read the timestamp as: Timestamp timestamp = (Timestamp)em.createNativeQuery("select clock_timestamp()").getSingleResult();  and pass the value to the Entity attribute.

Comment: @Vape I've update the answer on how to make that query from the EntityListener.

Comment: Thank you Vladucu, for your contribution!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :

```
 @PrePersist
 public void setDefaultTime(BaseEntity entity) {
   if(entity.getInsertTime() == null) {
       entity.setInsertTime(new Timestamp((new Date()).getTime())):
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jaganath, but in this way the timestamp from the "remote" server will be passed to the database. In my case have different servers and would like to have the timestamp which is on the database side.

Comment: ALTER TABLE {tablename} ALTER COLUMN SET DEFAULT current_timestamp

Comment: Please add some description to your answer

Comment: Hi Jaganath, I have a default value on the table column but anyway the value is overridden by JPA. Will try with this approach: first will read the timestamp as: Timestamp timestamp = (Timestamp)em.createNativeQuery("select clock_timestamp()").getSingleResult();  and then will pas those to Entity attribute. Is this approach ok?